# Ethernet working but no web browser connection

Tags: 13.10, wired

I can connect via terminal even ping sites as well as install, update packages; However I cannot connect to internet via Firefox. On the terminal i tried

```
firefox http://www.google .com
```

then firefox web browser shows

```
Forbidden you don't have permission to access/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Probably a network issue. How are you connecting to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using another browser.

Then that Firefox error can be as a result of that `www.google.com` is spelled wrong as
`www.google .com` and hence Firefox can't access it.